# Test to see if a string is in a row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code where there could be an instance of "Apple - Total", but it is very rare, while there will always be an instance of "Apple". How could I create a code to check whether the string exists in a row? The problem is at the moment is that the code bugs out if it is not there. If there is an instance of "Apple - Total" it should take priority over just "Apple". Something like the Try function in R would work.

```
If WorksheetFunction.Match(Apple & "-Total", Sheets("SOFP").Range("2:2"), 0) > 0 Then
        letr = WorksheetFunction.Match(Fund & "-Total", Sheets("SOFP").Range("2:2"), 0)
        letr = Split(Cells(, letr).Address, "$")(1)
        cur = Sheets("SOFP").Offset(1, 0).Value
    ElseIf WorksheetFunction.Match(Apple , Sheets("SOFP").Range("2:2"), 0) > 0 Then
        letr = WorksheetFunction.Match(Fund, Sheets("SOFP").Range("2:2"), 0)
        letr = Split(Cells(, letr).Address, "$")(1)
        cur = Trim(Sheets("SOFP").Offset(1, 0).Value)
    End If
```

Comment: On Error Goto and Labels you'll need, or a check first, Count if its there.  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: Any reason why you are not using `.Find`?

Comment: If you just want to ignore the error, you can add the statement `On Error Resume Next` below the declaration variables.

Comment: Beside using `.Find` you can also use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf()` to check for existence.

Comment: @Anastasiya, this would still call the rows underneath.

Comment: besides all what has already been pointed out about the `Match()` issue, there's also a syntax one in `Sheets("SOFP").Offset(1, 0).Value`. See my answer for both

Comment: @SiddharthRout as always you have the most sensible solution. On error is not really the way I want to go!

Answer (score 2):

Since:

- it's always better :

  - avoid `On Error Resume Next` approach

    which is quite dangerous and should be limited to a very few cases (like to check for any collection element)
  - use `Match()` function of the `Application` object instead of `WorksheetFunction` object

    because it traps the error into its return value and hence doesn't stop code execution upon possible `Match()` failure
- assuming:

  - you want to store into `cur` the value in the row beneath the proper column
  - `"Apple"` and `"Fund"` are two String *literals* and not String *variables*

a first approach, following more closely yours, could be the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim letr As Variant
    Dim cur As Double

    With Sheets("SOFP").Range("2:2") '<-- reference your worksheet row 2
        If Not IsError(Application.Match("Apple-Total", .Cells, 0)) Then '<-- if there's "Apple-Total"...
            letr = Application.Match("Fund-Total", .Cells, 0) '<-- ...then try finding "Fund-Total"
        ElseIf Not IsError(Application.Match("Apple", .Cells, 0)) Then '<-- otherwise if there's "Apple"...
            letr = Application.Match("Fund", .Cells, 0) '<-- ...then try finding "Fund"
        End If

        If Not IsError(letr) Then '<-- if the "proper Fund" has been succesfully found...
            letr = Split(Cells(, letr).Address, "$")(1) '<-- ...then get "proper Fund" column
            cur = Trim(.Range(letr & "2").Value) '<-- and return the value in the 3rd row (i.e. with a row index of 2 with reference to row "2")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

But you may want to consider the following "Find()" approach:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main2()
    Dim f As Range
    Dim cur As Double

    With Sheets("SOFP").Range("2:2") '<-- reference your worksheet row 2
        If Not .Find(what:="Apple-Total", LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then '<-- if "Apple-Total" has been found ...
            Set f = .Find(what:="Fund-Total", LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) '<-- ...then try finding "Fund-Total"
        ElseIf Not .Find(what:="Apple", LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then '<-- otherwise, if "Apple" has been found ...
            Set f = .Find(what:="Fund", LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) '<-- ...then try finding "Fund"
        End If
        If Not f Is Nothing Then cur = Trim(f.Offset(1).Value) '<-- if the "proper Fund" has been succesfully found then store the value in row 3 of its corresponding column
    End With
End Sub
```

which I think is much neater

Comment: I agree. `.Find` is much neater

Comment: @Lowpar: did you get through it?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

If iserror(application.match)... and handle it that way

Answer (score 0):

```
On error goto TryApple

'  try for total and goto eHandle if found

TryApple:

On error goto eHandle

' try for Apple

eHandle:
```

The first try for total is like the Try, TryApple is like catch, and eHandle is default